# Symfony2 Login - Bad Credentials | Doctrine does not receive any parameters

Tags: symfony, authentication, doctrine, credentials

I'm a symfony newbie and I'm trying to create a registration and login form. I've been successful with registration so far. But login form keeps returning "Bad Credentials" error to me. I checked a lot of threads with this problem, but I can't seem to figure it out. 
I've created User.php, which has some basics:

```
<?php
    namespace Money\MainBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="user")
     * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken", groups="registration")
     * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken", groups="registration")
     */
    class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
    {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups="registration")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email(groups="registration")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups="registration")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups="registration")
     * @Assert\MinLength(limit=4, groups="registration", message="Your password needs to have at least 4 characters")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * constructor
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    /**
     * setters
     */

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    /**
     * advanced
     */

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

then I have security.yml

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Money\MainBundle\Entity\User: 
            algorithm: sha512   
            encode_as_base64: true
            iterations: 10

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        user_db:
            entity: { class: Money\MainBundle\Entity\User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/dashboard
            form_login:
                check_path: /dashboard/login_check
                login_path: /login
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/dashboard, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I create the login form with

```
class LoginForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username', 'text', array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Username', 'class' => 'span12')));
        $builder->add('password', 'password', array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Password', 'class' => 'span12')));
    }

    // public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    // {
    //     return array(
    //         'data_class' => 'Money\MainBundle\Entity\User'
    //     );
    // }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'login';
    }
}
```

and the login action is here

```
public function loginAction()
    {
        //create login form
        $form = $this->createForm(new LoginForm(), new User());
        //request
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(
                SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
            );
        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return $this->render(
            'MoneyMainBundle:Main:signup.html.twig',
            array(
                'error' => $error,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'register' => false
            )
        );
    }
```

also I encode my password like this:

```
public function signUpAction()
{
    //create valid form entity
    $form = $this->createForm(new RegisterForm(), new User());
    //check request
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            //useful variables
            $user = $form->getData();
            $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
            //encode password
            $pass = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt());
            $user->setPassword($pass);
            //save data to db
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('money_main_dashboard'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('MoneyMainBundle:Main:signup.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'register' => true,
        'error' => false
    ));
}
```

and lastly, the log is here:

```
Marker - Feb 4, 2013 12:02:57 AM
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] request.INFO: Matched route "money_main_login_check" (parameters: "_route": "money_main_login_check") [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username AS username2, t0.email AS email3, t0.password AS password4, t0.is_active AS is_active5, t0.salt AS salt6 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.username = ? LIMIT 1 ["NONE_PROVIDED"] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] security.INFO: Authentication request failed: Bad credentials [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] security.DEBUG: Redirecting to /login [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.request". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest" was not called for event "kernel.request". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] request.INFO: Matched route "money_main_login" (parameters: "_controller": "Money\MainBundle\Controller\MainController::loginAction", "_route": "money_main_login") [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt" (parameters: "_controller": "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\Controller\ProfilerController::toolbarAction", "token": "510eeca5b649c", "_route": "_wdt") [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
```

the important part should be the doctrine debug:

```
[2013-02-04 00:03:01] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username AS username2, t0.email AS email3, t0.password AS password4, t0.is_active AS is_active5, t0.salt AS salt6 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.username = ? LIMIT 1 ["NONE_PROVIDED"] []
```

but I have no idea why it doesn't receive any post parameters

Comment: how you implemented signUpAction() helped me solve my similar issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that name values in input fields were login[username] and login[password] and I couldn't change those names to _username and _password (which login_check accepts) so I had to create a form by hand (without abstract type and form builder) and now it works.

Comment: You could have used these settings in your security.yml to rename your username and password fields : username_parameter: assword_parameter:

Answer (score 0):

if your form type class return an empty string or null in the getName method then your inputs should have the propers names

```
class LoginType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('_username')->add('_password', 'password');
    }   

    public function getName() {
        return '';
    }
}
```

that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

just make the twig template and give the fields the names '_username' and '_password'. The magic should be done for you then.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enter the following in the security.yml, if you created your own form class:

```
username_parameter: login[username]
password_parameter: login[password]
```